# oralce import joinning 2 tables using query

Tags: oracle, import

Is it possible to join 2 tables inside the query in oracle while importing ? I have a dump for 2 tables tab1 and tab2. and I am trying to query on 1 of the tables:

```
Directory=backup
DUMPFILE=twotables.dmp
logfile=tablesimp.log
tables =  tab1,tab2
Query=tab1:"WHERE code= 2
AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM tab2 b WHERE type=b.type and numb=b.numb)"
```

it just give me 0 rows Imported.

Comment: So what are you doing? You said you are 'importing', but then you say it reports '0 rows _exported_'.  What version of oracle (to 4 digits)?  Exactly which utility are you using? imp, impdp, exp, or expdp?  What do you get if you just execute the implied query in sqlplus 

select * from tab1 
where code=2 
  and not exists (select 1 
                  from tab2 b 
                  where type=b.type
                    and numb=b.numb
                  );

Comment: @EdStevens i am using impdp , i fixed the error i meant rows imported, if i applied in sql plus it works normaly, the problem was in alias and it worked , the below is the link for your knowledge https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64552889/oracle-import-joinning-2-tables-using-query/64553029#64553029